# Running byobu inside Webstorm console gives error: Sessions should be nested with care

Tags: linux, byobu, webstorm

I am trying to run byobu (based from tmux) inside the webstorm console but I always get this error:

> ERROR: Sessions should be nested with care. Unset $TMUX to force.

Normal terminal windows work fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Webstorm, but if you're getting that message, then you're already running inside of a tmux console.  Can you post a screen shot?  You can force [byobu](http://byobu.co) to launch by running:

```
unset TMUX; byobu
```

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: Thanks, your command works, now I have the Webstorm terminal mirroring the byobu session in my open terminal window. I was trying to get webstorm to have its own independent byobu session, is this possible?